# what is the difference between a portlet and a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, portlet

I have been asked to work on portlets and portals, and I want to know the differences between a portlet and a servlet.

How and where does a portlet differ (maybe functionally) from a servlet?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Portlets are part of JSR-168 standard that regulates portal containers and components. This is different standard from standards for web containers (and servlets). Though there are definitely strong parallels between these two standards they differ in containers, APIs, life cycle, configuration, deployment, etc.

The main difference between portlet vs. servlet could be that while servlet always responds to single type of action - *request*, portlet (due to nature of its life cycle and stronger container bindings) has to respond to two types of actions: *render* and *request*. There are of course more to it but I found this as the core difference between the two when I studied portal development.

Comment: Update: Portlets 1 is [JSR 168](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=168), Portlets 2 is  [JSR 286](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286), and Portlet 3 is [JSR 362](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=362).

Answer (score 145):

***Enhanced from Source***: [Servlets Vs Portlets](http://fanatech.wordpress.com/servlets-vs-portlets/)

> **Similarities**
>
> 1. Servlets and Portlets are web based components which use Java for
>    their implementation.
> 2. Portlets are managed by a portlet container just like servlet is
>    managed by servlet container.
> 3. Both static and dynamic content can be generated by Portlets and
>    Servlets.
> 4. The life cycle of portlets and servlets is controlled by the container
> 5. The client/server model is used for both servlets and portlets
> 6. The packaging and deployment are essentially the same, WAR/EARs.
> 7. Application Session exists in both Servlet and Portlet containers. It is one of the ways of of sharing data (crude Inter-Portlet Communication) from the render phase to the action phase (or any lower phases) in the portlet containers.
> 8. Both Servlets and Portlets use similar server / VM environments that support it. Although, some additional configurations might needed in case of portlets to make it tick
> 9. The build/DI tools are similar for both - Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc are all supported. Mostly :) - This has changed a bit with Liferay 7.

---

> **Dissimilarities**
>
> 1. Servlets can render complete web pages, whereas portlets renders html
>    fragments. These fragments are aggregated by the portal into a
>    complete web page.
> 2. The content type of JSR 168 portlets can be only cHTML, XHTML, WML. It
>    does not support other content types.
> 3. Portlets are not allowed to generate HTML code that contains tags such
>    as body, frame, frameset, head, html, or title.
> 4. A Portlet unlike a servlet doesn’t have URL attached to it so it
>    cannot be accessed directly. Access is only through the portal page
>    which holds the portlet.
> 5. Portlets can be provided with controls to manipulate its window states
>    or portlet modes.
> 6. Multiple instances of a single portlet can be placed onto the same
>    page.
> 7. Portlets support persistent configuration and customization, profile
>    information.
> 8. Portlets can have two types of request viz. render request and action
>    request.
> 9. Portlets have two scopes within session; application scope for
>    communication across portlets and portlet scope for intra portlet
>    communication.
> 10. Portlet cannot set the character set encoding of the response nor can
>     it set the HTTP response headers.
> 11. Portlets doesn’t have access to request URL. So it cannot access the
>     query parameters appended to the URL. Portlets cannot set cookies.
> 12. Typical methods of Portlet API are `doView()`, `doEdit()`, `doHelp()` and
>     `processAction()` while those of servlet are `service()`, `doPost()`,
>     `doGet()`.
> 13. *Servlet Specifications* - JSR 369(Servlet 4.0), JSR 340(Servlet 3.1), JSR 315(Servlet 3.0), JSR 154(Servlet 2.5 & 2.4).
>     *Portlet Specifications* - JSR 168(Portlet Spec v1.0), JSR 286(Portlet Spec v2.0), JSR 362(Portlet Spec v3.0)
> 14. Deployment of Portlets involves [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260119/how-to-deploy-portlets-to-liferay) than a Servlet application. Some Providers (Liferay/Alfresco/WebSphere) support hot-deploying of portlets without the need to restart the server which is not possible in case of servlets without modularizing the application using special libraries such as OSGi.

---

**Edit** <sub>(From comments)</sub>

A Portlet container is built on a Servlet container. So ultimately it can be said that the portlet runs on a Servlet Container. But while developing apps, we view a portlet container separately from the Servlet/Java EE container.

Comment: So, a portal application runs in a servlet/JEE container and talks to a portlet container separately? The client's machine (browser) is not aware of the portlet container or portlets as I understand it, Other than the appearance on the page which is handled via JavaScript and partial-page refreshes.

Comment: A Portlet container is built on a Servlet container. You can say that a Portlet container is an advanced Servlet container with many 'features'. But to answer your question bluntly, yes. While developing apps, we view a portlet container separately from the Servlet/JEE container.

Comment: The simplest way to think of this is that a servlet renders an entire web page, and a portlet renders a specific rectangular part (subsection) of a web page. For example, the advertising bar on the right hand side of a news page could be rendered as a portlet.  But you wouldn't implement a single edit field as a portlet, because that's too granular.  Basically if you break down a web page into it's major sectional areas, those are good candidates to make into portlets.

Comment: @ClayFerguson "a portlet renders a specific rectangular part (subsection) of a web page", so it's like a frame, or a <div>...

Comment: @TomBrito - Partly true. It's like a frame or a div, which have their own lifecycles and can share data with other frames or divs.

Answer (score 9):

Both portlets and servlets receive an http request and return a response, which is usally some HTML that can be rendered by a browser. A portlet is used in the context of a "Portal", the idea being that a single page seen by the user has lots of parts, think tiles, each coming from a different portlet.

Now, you can get that "tiled" effect from normal servets (See Struts + Tiles for an example of how) the extra bit from the portlets is that the portlets are in a richer environment provided by the Portal, extra APIs are provided so that what is displayed by any portlet can be configured by individual users to their preferences, and the porlets can communicate with each other - press a button in one, something happens in a another.

Answer (score 6):

Servlets have a java definition (applications which handle HTTP GET/POST requests), while portlets have a user interface definition.A component performing a specific function similar to the windows vista widgets or a lot of components used in stackoverflow here. They need not necessarily be backed by servlets on the server side. But the Portlet standard was developed alongside java. O'Reilly has a nice [tutorial](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/what-is-a-portlet.html).

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, Servlets provide content that normally takes up the whole page in a browser (unless you're using frames), and portlets provide content that is wrapped by a window. With portlets, you can have multiple portlets side by side with one another and each one can provide content and functionality that is different from the other. A portlet can provide the complete interaction for one type of application, while another portlet can provide content for another type of application. The portal can provide some house keeping functionality and secured single point of entry to all of the portlets on a page. As for the particulars (similarities/differences) between them, please continue reading. Here are some similarities: Servlets and portlets are web based components that utilize Java for their implementation Portlets are managed by a portlet container similar to a servlet container Both of these components generate content, which can be static or dynamic